# Calculate driving distance matrix between several points (using osrm)

Tags: r, osrm

I have two spatial points dataframes. One of the files contain information on the latitude and the longitude of people's residences (n=98). The second file contains information on latitude and the longitude of different polling stations (n=300). I need to:
1) Calculate the driving distance between people's residences and all polling stations.
2) Identify the closest polling station based on the shortest driving distance.

I wanted to use the gmapsdistance package (and the Google Maps API), but I easily hit the query limit. Is there any solution to this?
Alternatively, I thought of using the OpenStreetMap package, but I can't find any tutorial online. 
Many thanks!

Comment: The Google Maps Directions API is the best way to do this activity, it is a service that calculates directions between locations. But like you said it has a limit of 2,500 free requests per day. But you can pay $0.50 USD for 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily. If you have the money, then I suggest you to use this because it is the bast API to show the things that you want.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use the geosphere package to calculate the geographic distance between the residences and the polling places then only find the driving distances for the closest ones (maybe the closest 3-5)  to each residences.  You can reduce your Google query from a few thousand to a few hundred.